# How to read regular expressions?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

Consider the following regular expressions

```
letter = a + b + c + d

LETTER = A + B + C + D
digit = 4+5+6+7+9
R1 = (LETTER + digit + !) • (letter • digit)∗• (letter + digit)
R2 = (LETTER + digit + ?) • (letter + digit)∗• (LETTER + digit)
R3 = (digit + ? + !) • (letter∗• digit∗)∗• (LETTER + letter)
R4 = (digit • letter + ? + !) • (letter∗• digit∗) • (LETTER)
```

I'm not sure what some of the characters mean ('+' , '•' , '*')?

Do I read regex backwards when check if a string is an element of L(R1)?

```
FOR EXAMPLE: !5aA ELEMENT/NOT ELEMENT L(R1)

R1 = (LETTER + digit + !) • (letter • digit)∗• (letter + digit)

!5aA is an element of L(R1) I would think, but that's just a guess.
```

If someone can point me in the right direction to read a regex like this it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: So after considering Yuval answer this starts to make a whole lot of sense to me so thank you.  It seems like the correct language for the string !5aA is L(R3) AND/OR L(R4) not sure which exactly yet, maybe its both.  I like to think the + as OR's (not multiples) the • as a concatenation (or no concatenations) and * as all combinations.  Treating • as multiplication using the commutative property holds true, makes sense for the order of the chars.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question.  You might want to take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form.

Comment: TCS is rather simple this way: look at the definition.

Comment: Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Comment: There must be hundreds of resources online and in textbooks that tell you how to read a regular expression. Did you read any of them? What didn't you understand in them? It doesn't seem to be worth anyone's time to replicate a huge number of existing resources without even knowing what's wrong with them.

Answer (score 1):

The symbols you quote have the following meaning:

- $+$ means *or*: $L(r_1 + r_2) = L(r_1) \cup L(r_2)$.
- $\cdot$ means *concatenation*: $L(r_1 \cdot r_2) = \{ xy : x \in L(r_1), y \in L(r_2) \}$.
- $^*$ means *iteration*: $L(r^*) = \{ \epsilon \} \cup L(r) \cup L(r \cdot r) \cup L(r \cdot r \cdot r) \cup \cdots$.

(Here $\epsilon$ is the empty word, sometimes denoted $\lambda$.)

Now let us consider your example:
$$
R_1 = (\mathsf{LETTER} + \mathsf{digit} + \mathsf{!}) \cdot (\mathsf{letter} \cdot \mathsf{digit})^* \cdot (\mathsf{letter} + \mathsf{digit}).
$$
All words in $L(R_1)$ end in a lowercase letter $a,b,c,d$ or in a digit $4,5,6,7,9$. The word $!5aA$ ends in neither, so doesn't belong to $L(R_1)$.